# Jersey deploy file to activiti-rest service 500 message from the service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, webservice-client, activiti

im trying to connect to activiti-rest service. i want to deploy a bpmn file with the service ,so i created a client side using jersey, but after i run the class a 500 message received from the service.

```
package org.cacib.beans;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;


import javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Cookie;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.BodyPart;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;

public class ActivitiTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
/**
 * @param args
 */
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


 ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
 Client client = Client.create(config);
 client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("kermit", "kermit"));
 WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 Cookie c = new Cookie("succes","true");
 FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();  
 File f = new File("C:/workspace-indigo/apurement/src/main/resources/diagrams/apurement.bpmn");

 multiPart.bodyPart( new FileDataBodyPart("file", f,MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE)); 




 ClientResponse user = service.path("deployment").accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).header("Content-type",MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class,multiPart);
 try {
    System.out.println(user);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}



}
private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://192.168.1.6:8080/activiti-rest/service/").build();
  }
}
```

[image: screen shot for restClient]

Comment: Please post your "a 500 message received from the service". That should help along with the Stack Trace if possible.

Comment: there is no stack trace just POST http://192.168.1.6:8080/activiti-rest/service/deployment returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Use [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/) Plugin for Firefox and issue the same POST Request. Internal Server Error means that your service threw some exception during it's execution.

Comment: i used it but nothing happends

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the RESTClient if possible?

Comment: @AnisBouchenafa what is needed to answer this question is most likely in the `Response Body` tab in RESTClient. If it's not there, you'll have to look in the server logs.

Comment: @AnisBouchenafa Did you figure out the issue?

Comment: well , no i think the problem is in the body request.

Comment: @Anis Bouchenafa Hi, I am also using Activiti Rest to deploy process diagram but I also getting the same error. Have you got any solution for this problem? please share. Thanks.

Comment: @Jignesh , no i did not solve the problem but i moved on in activiti rest. so if you need some thing just send me a message. ok

Comment: The solution is to have the bpmn file's name suffixed with ".bpmn20.xml".